# Is 30 % deviance explained normal for behavioral data?

Tags: predictive-models

My data consists of the behavior of animals. The "behavior", which we just call $y$, has a lot of variation. I have fitted a regression model, and my $R^2$ is at $30 \%$.

The purpose is inference, not necessarily prediction, but still, is this sort of $R^2$ acceptable for such data?

This is the first time I am doing analysis on my own, when I used to do exercises in class, I would always get $R^2> 70 \%$, so I am a little worried here.

Comment: Surely as a subject-specific (what is normally seen with animal behavior data) issue this question would be the province of experts in animal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

An R-Squared of .30 is not bad, though this is dependent on (1) how many predictor variables you are using and (2) what kind of regression model you are using.

If you are using simple linear regression (only one predictor), said predictor expresses a statistically significant relationship with your dependent variable, and you have no serious outliers, then this result is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

In human psychology, R^2s of 0.30 are pretty commonplace, because people vary a lot, and because the mind really is a complex thing. However, in psychology, we would be measuring things like score on a personality test, or scores on a test of implicit racism, or things of that nature. Our minds are more complex than animals, and you may be measuring behaviors that are simpler. In that case, 0.30 might be low, but perhaps not alarmingly so.

Then again, animals are complex creatures, and some animals are more complex than others, so an R-squared of 0.30 might be perfectly in line with what others expect. Bottom line: know the subject matter, know the ins and outs of the measure, and in your case, know the animal.

Aside, R^2 is not deviance, it's the proportion of variation in the (continuous) outcome you explain (in a linear model, or some variation of a linear model).